# How to write many functions depending on each other in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have some functions are depending on each ther , the functions are from this book page 136 http://www.cs.helsinki.fi/u/ahyvarin/papers/bookfinal_ICA.pdf .. I functions are presented below , How to write following functions in matlab ??

```
y(t) = W(t-1)*x(t)
h(t) = P(t-1)*y(t)
P(t)=(1/B)*Tri[P(t-1)-m(t)*h^T(t)]
m(t) = h(t)/(B+y^T(t))*h(t))
e(t) = x(t)-W^T(t-1)*y(t)
W(t) = W(t-1) + m(t)*e^T(t)
```

It is solving the weight matrix W(t) iteratively .. I tried to do like this in matlab but I did not work so may be you can advice to correct the code :

```
    for i=1:10 
    e=randn(3,5000);
A=[1 0 0;-0.5 0.5 0;0.3 0.1 0.1];
x=A*e;
    y(t) = W(t-1)*x(t)
    h(t) = P(t-1)*y(t)
    P(t)=(1/B)*Tri[P(t-1)-m(t)*h^T(t)]
    m(t) = h(t)/(B+y^T(t))*h(t))
    e(t) = x(t)-W^T(t-1)*y(t)
    W(t) = W(t-1) + m(t)*e^T(t) 

    end
```

Thanks

Comment: I don't know about everybody else but I'm certainly not a mind reader. You'll have to tell me how it did not work? You should take a look at [ask] and [mcve] and then come back here and edit your question to make it easier for us to answer.

Comment: matlab says : can not run because it contains an invalid statement `P(t)=(1/B)*Tri[P(t-1)-m(t)*h^T(t)];`

Comment: You seem to have several uninitialized arrays, and I suspect that you want to loop over `t` for however many elements `W(t)` is supposed to have.

Comment: where are you brothers????????????

Comment: I'm still on page 10... it's going to take me some time. Though I can tell you that the text tells you what `Tri[...]` means just below the code. I think you're going to have to understand the math, then learn some Matlab basics before you try to tackle this problem.

Comment: @code Jeez, I didn't realise I had a brother, sorry. Where have you been my whole life?

Comment: We aren't all brothers.  There are sisters here too.....

Comment: thank you , you are my brother in humanity :)

Comment: sisters too of course :)

Comment: You seem nice... but I have no idea what you're asking lol.

Comment: thank you sister rayryeng ... even me not good in matlab :)

Comment: @rayryeng, it wouldn't be **THAT** bad. If it had proper initialization, and some functions were explained, it would be a regular set of quantities which can be computed iteratively to obtain *something*.

Comment: @code - You're very welcome sister code.

Comment: @AndrasDeak The only **input** seems to be `x()`, but we have no idea what the dimensions of any of the elements are.

Comment: @beaker We are all waiting until you reach page 136...

Comment: @beaker Well, `x()` and index number `0` of all those quantities in the iteration. The initialization would explain most of the missing info... Oh, and `B` and `T()`:D

Comment: look at the edit please .. thanks

Comment: @code, I didn't know you could do that, but you just made it even worse:(

Comment: Brother @code Line: 7 Column: 19 - `Unbalanced or unexpected parenthesis or bracket.`

Comment: @AndrasDeak no, not actually... we have `x` now...

Comment: I think `B`  can be initialized to B=0.5;

Comment: `B` is the *forgetting factor*. `B = 1` forgets nothing and `B = 0` breaks the bond between brothers.

Comment: @code I think `x` is supposed to be a vector, not a 3x5000 matrix, right?

Comment: sorry I do not now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I can't really understand what you want, but your code shows that you don't understand some moments. I will try to clarify some moments to you:

```
for i = 2:10
x = rand(3);
y = W(:,:,i-1)*x;
h = P(:,:,i-1)*y;
m=h/(1+y'*h);
P(:,:,i)=P(:,:,i-1)*m*h';
e=x-W(:,:,i-1)'*y;
W(:,:,i)=W(:,:,i-1)+m*e';
end
```

You must go something like this: 1. you calculate x and use it to calculate other functions. 
2. all of them are matrices. So you need to define it first. For example `y = ones(3)` etc. 3.Thats not y^T or e^T. Its transposing. If you do not feel difference it's early for you to solve this task :)
And the last: Tri function will create a some kind of problems to you, but it's defined at 136 page.

P.S. i missed `beta` becouse of don't know what is it :)

Comment: Does it make sense to redefine `x` in every iteration with a new value? Is that intentional?

Comment: @AndrasDeak really I got this from @code's example (`e=randn(3,5000);` and just simplified it. But for correct answer we need to read this linked book. I glanced this and I think `x` is not random number - it has some determination a few pages earlier